# Speed Up Pandas DataFrame Groupby Apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following code that I found on another post here (and modified slightly). It works great and the output is just as I expect, however I am wondering if anyone has suggestions on speed improvements. I am comparing two dataframes with about 93,000 rows and 110 columns. It takes about 20 minutes for the groupby to complete. I have tried to think of ways to speed if up but haven't come across anything. I am trying to think of anything now before my data sizes increase in the future. I am also open to other ways of doing this!

```
###Function that is called to check values in dataframe groupby     
def report_diff(x):
        return 'SAME' if x[0] == x[1] else '{} | {}'.format(*x)
        #return '' if x[0] == x[1] else '{} | {}'.format(*x)

print("Concatening CSV and XML data together...")
###Concat the dataframes together
df_all = pd.concat(
    [df_csv, df_xml], 
    axis='columns', 
    keys=['df_csv', 'df_xml'],
    join='outer',
)
print("Done")

print("Swapping column levels...")
###Display keys at the top of each column
df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df_xml.columns[0:]]
print("Done")

df_final = df_final.fillna('None')

print("Grouping data and checking for matches...")
###Apply report_diff function to each row
df_excel = df_final.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda frame: frame.apply(report_diff, axis=1))
```

Comment: Could you create a bit of dummy data for `df_csv` and `df_xml` (preferably in dictionary format)? I feel this could be significantly sped up using vectorised operations/

Comment: @SvenHarris I am sorry, can you clarify? Are you saying you want to see some dummy data? The data in these two variables is read in from a CSV and XML file, respectively, and then massaged a lot before these steps.

Comment: Just a small reproducible example like `df_csv = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]})`, it will help understand how the code runs and verify that answers given return the expected values.

Comment: @SvenHarris Hopefully this is helpful, this is some sample data (modified)
df_csv.head(2).to_dict()
Out[84]: 
'I1SP-1C': {'123456789': 'COMMON STOCK', '987654321': 'COMMON STOCK'},
 'I1SP-1E': {'123456789': 'DIVIDENDSCOMMON', '987654321': 'DIVIDENDSCOMMON'},
 'I1SP-3C': {'123456789': 'HEALTH CARE PROVIDERS & SERVICES','987654321': 'BUILDING PRODUCTS'},
 'I1SP-3E': {'123456789': 'BQZJBY4', '987654321': '2268130'},
 'I1SP-3Z': {'123456789': '0', '987654321': '0'},

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and check where `df_csv[df_xml.columns]` is equal to `df_xml`, if `True` then the value is `'SAME'` else you can join the values of both dataframes like you do.

**SETUP**

```
df_csv = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4),'b':[0,0,1,1],'c':list('abcd')})
df_xml = pd.DataFrame({'b':[0,2,3,1],'c':list('bbce')})
```

**METHOD**

```
df_excel = pd.DataFrame( np.where( df_csv[df_xml.columns] == df_xml, #find where
                                   'SAME', #True
                                   df_csv[df_xml.columns].astype(str) + ' | ' + df_xml.astype(str)), #False
                        columns=df_xml.columns
                        index=df_xml.index)

print (df_excel)
       b      c
0   SAME  a | b
1  0 | 2   SAME
2  1 | 3   SAME
3   SAME  d | e
```

Which is the same result that I got with your method.

Comment: This is awesome and works great except that I lose both of my index columns when I do it this way, is there I can keep the index columns here as well?

Comment: EDIT: I added "index=df_xml.index" to the end of the pd.DataFrame code and it seems to work fine! This is so much faster than the original code! Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisBrown good point for the index, I did not consider they were important. I'll edit my answer to include it :)

Comment: So I have another dilemma with this...any idea how to run code like this with duplicate index values? Is that even possible? I am getting this error when trying this code with duplicate index values: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: @ChrisBrown it is duplicated index or it is because some index values in `df_xml` are not in `df_csv` or vice-versa? if it is the second case, you can use `reindex` before such as `df_csv = df_csv.reindex(df_xml.index)`. If it is the first case, then what would be the expected result of comparing two values from df_csv to one value from df_xml or something like this?

Comment: The issue is that both dataframes contain duplicate index values, say 10 rows of "123456" in the index and each row then contains some different values, so each row needs compared. I am thinking the only way to do this is with a composite index of some kind, and I will just have to find another field to add to the index..

Comment: @ChrisBrown I see, then you can do for example on both `df_csv` and `df_xlm` somehting like `df_csv.index = df_csv.index.astype(str).values + '_' + df_csv.groupby(level=0).cumcount().astype(str).values`, and then compare them. If you want to use the original index in `df_excel`, you can save the original index in a variable before doing this and use it to create the output dataframe.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! That works great, you have been a life-saver!